# IE8 don't show arguments.callee.caler when function called from child iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, internet-explorer-8

Firstly, sorry for my English.

Actually, I have HTML page with one child IFRAME. Into top script I defined function

```
function showCaller() { alert(arguments.callee.caller); }
```

And script into child iframe caliing this function like that:

```
function testTopCalling() { top.showCaller(); }
```

I expected to get the function "testTopCalling" body, but result is "null". I ckecked this code in Chrome and IE8. Chrome returns correct result. I can't understand why IE8 doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Do newer versions of IE work?

Comment: not sure why it wouldn't be working in IE8, but be aware that [`arguments.callee` is deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments/callee) and has been removed from ES5, so I wouldn't base any new, intended to be long term code, on it

Comment: @JamesThorpe It has been removed from ES5 _strict mode_, not ES5.

Comment: @JLRishe You're right - and I had intended to put that in my comment, but missed it whilst getting the link in

Comment: @JamesThorpe In all likelihood, it will continue to be around for a long time, but I enthusiastically agree with the sentiment that it should be avoided.

Comment: I am developing User Interface for application which uses IE8 WebBrowser Control for displaying interface. So, I can't use any other browser. But sometimes I use Chrome for debugging modules. Note, If both of functions placed into one window (top or iframe) IE8 shows caller correctly.

Comment: @IvanGredyaev Take a read of the page I linked to as to why it was added in the first place, and perhaps think why you think you need to use it in your situation, as there is probably a better way to structure your code